# Excel 2007: Remove rows by duplicates in column value

Tags: excel, excel-2007, duplicates

I have a table in excel. E.g.

```
col1    col2
A       Something    
A       Something else   
A       Something more   
A       Something blahblah   
B       Something Fifth   
B       Something xth
C       Som thin
F       Summerthing
F       Boom
```

And I want only rows without duplicate col1: e.g:

```
col1    col2
A       Something    
B       Something Fifth   
C       Som thin
F       Boom
```

Is there any way of filtering rows like this :) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it myself:

> To remove duplicate values, use the Remove Duplicates command in the
>   Data Tools group on the Data tab.

Comment: Also see:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJj5bDsP8vc from Mr Excel on how to do this.

Comment: The problem with removing duplicates from a single column is that it will move up the data in that row and mess up the correlation in a row.

Comment: Agree with Amala. For anything more than 1 column this answer is useless.