# How to find duplicate rows in Excel

Tags: excel

Hi this is my excel sheet. i want to eliminate the duplicate values from A to B

```
A       B
1       1
519     18
640     19
475     20
216     24
639     26
950     28
519     519
```

Comment: which ones do you think are duplicates to be eliminated in your example??

Comment: I really try not to give this answer or this comment but, please [**use the search function**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[excel]+duplicates)!

Comment: for instance, possible duplicate of [Excel 2007: Remove rows by duplicates in column value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081306/excel-2007-remove-rows-by-duplicates-in-column-value)

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd like to use the [VLOOKUP function](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelfunctions/ss/vlookup.htm) :)