# Remove row if duplicate exists in column

Tags: excel, duplicates

How do I remove a row if a duplicate exists in say the first column?

Imagine the following scenario:

[image]

You can see that `A9 = A12` but notice also that `B9 != B11`. The current "remove duplicates" function in Excel 2010 only removes the whole row if the whole is identical to the other one.

Any suggestions?

~Solved thanks to pnuts!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel 2007: Remove rows by duplicates in column value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081306/excel-2007-remove-rows-by-duplicates-in-column-value)

Comment: In an effort to remove duplicates, this is a Possible Duplicate of [this question about removing duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081306/excel-2007-remove-rows-by-duplicates-in-column-value), also answered by the person who posted the question.

Comment: Exactly, I was well aware of the function before posting. Just not of the use pnuts talked about.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to read this page: [Excel remove rows based on cell value](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/815-excel-remove-rows-based-on-cell-value.html)

Comment: Thanks but pnuts comment actually solved my problem. What I did wrong was that I didn't select the whole sheet when I used the remove duplicate function. I had only selected the first column.